# How to create Blur Eraser and Blur Drawing effect in JQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I want to make **blur erasing** and **blur drawing** effect in JQuery or Javascript. I have written the code for erasing the blurred image when I hover it and to reveal the unblurred image. Here's the screenshot.
[image]

I am able to erase the blur image when I hover over the image, but I couldn't redraw the blurred image at the same position, may be like after 500ms. How do I redraw the blur again over where I hovered with my mouse?

Here's the code for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blur Testing</title>
    <meta name="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #item {
            background: url("http://i66.tinypic.com/2z6uq9f.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="item"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('item');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            img = new Image,
            radius = 30;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    $('#item').css({
        "-webkit-filter": "blur(0px)",
        "filter": "blur(0px)"
    });
    $(img).on('load', function () {
        $('#item').mouseover(function (e) {
            erase(getXY(e));
        }).mousemove(function (e) {
            erase(getXY(e));
            //setTimeout(redraw(getXY(e)), 400);
        });

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    });
    img.src = 'http://i64.tinypic.com/14mt7yx.jpg';
    img.width = window.width;
    img.height = window.height;

    function getXY(e) {
        var r = $('#item')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        return {x: e.clientX - r.left, y: e.clientY - r.top};
    }
//    function redraw(pos) {
//        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
//        ctx.beginPath();
//        ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
//        ctx.closePath();
//        ctx.fill();
//    };
    function erase(pos) {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a quick modification on [Alpha Mask Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34864970/3877726) question. I have simply reversed the blur and sharp images. See the linked question for details.

The extra bit to fade out the blur mask

```
    blurMaskFadeCounter += 1;
    if((blurMaskFadeCounter % blurMaskFadeRate) === 0){
        maskImage.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
        maskImage.ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        maskImage.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
        maskImage.ctx.fillRect(0,0,maskImage.width,maskImage.height);
        maskImage.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        maskImage.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    }
```

Simply draws over the mask with destination-out composition and alpha set low. It is timed to every so many frames to slow it down. If you set alpha below 0.1 you get some pixels that wont completely clear so the frame skipping give a slower response

```js
var imageLoadedCount = 0;
var error = false;
var maskImage;
var flowerImage;
var flowerImageBlur;
/** ImageTools.js begin **/
var imageTools = (function () {
    var tools = {
        canvas : function (width, height) {  // create a blank image (canvas)
            var c = document.createElement("canvas");
            c.width = width;
            c.height = height;
            return c;
        },
        createImage : function (width, height) {
            var image = this.canvas(width, height);
            image.ctx = image.getContext("2d");
            return image;
        },
        loadImage : function (url, callback) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = url;
            image.addEventListener('load', callback);
            image.addEventListener('error', callback);
            return image;
        }
    };
    return tools;
})();




var mouse;
var demo = function(){
    /** fullScreenCanvas.js begin **/
    var canvas = (function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
        if(canvas !== null){
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
        // creates a blank image with 2d context
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 
        canvas.id = "canv";    
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.top = "0px";
        canvas.style.left = "0px";
        canvas.style.zIndex = 1000;
        canvas.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        return canvas;
    })();
    var ctx = canvas.ctx;
    
    /** fullScreenCanvas.js end **/
    /** MouseFull.js begin **/
    if(typeof mouse !== "undefined"){  // if the mouse exists 
        if( mouse.removeMouse !== undefined){
            mouse.removeMouse(); // remove previouse events
        }
    }else{
        var mouse;
    }
    var canvasMouseCallBack = undefined;  // if needed
    mouse = (function(){
        var mouse = {
            x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false,
            interfaceId : 0, buttonLastRaw : 0,  buttonRaw : 0,
            over : false,  // mouse is over the element
            bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], // masks for setting and clearing button raw bits;
            getInterfaceId : function () { return this.interfaceId++; }, // For UI functions
            startMouse:undefined,
            mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
        };
        function mouseMove(e) {
            var t = e.type, m = mouse;
            m.x = e.offsetX; m.y = e.offsetY;
            if (m.x === undefined) { m.x = e.clientX; m.y = e.clientY; }
            m.alt = e.altKey;m.shift = e.shiftKey;m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
            if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1];
            } else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2];
            } else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false;
            } else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true;
            } else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta;
            } else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail;}
            if (canvasMouseCallBack) { canvasMouseCallBack(mouse); }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        function startMouse(element){
            if(element === undefined){
                element = document;
            }
            mouse.element = element;
            mouse.mouseEvents.forEach(
                function(n){
                    element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove);
                }
            );
            element.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {e.preventDefault();}, false);
        }
        mouse.removeMouse = function(){
            if(mouse.element !== undefined){
                mouse.mouseEvents.forEach(
                    function(n){
                        mouse.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove);
                    }
                );
                canvasMouseCallBack = undefined;
            }
        }
        mouse.mouseStart = startMouse;
        return mouse;
    })();
    if(typeof canvas !== "undefined"){
        mouse.mouseStart(canvas);
    }else{
        mouse.mouseStart();
    }
    /** MouseFull.js end **/
    
    // load the images and create the mask
    if(imageLoadedCount === 0){
        imageLoadedCount = 0;
        error = false;
        maskImage;
        flowerImage =    imageTools.loadImage("http://www.createjs.com/demos/_assets/art/flowers.jpg", function (event) {
            if (event.type === "load") {
                imageLoadedCount += 1;
            } else {
                error = true;
            }
        })
        flowerImageBlur = imageTools.loadImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S5m8.jpg", function () {
            if (event.type === "load") {
                maskImage = imageTools.createImage(this.width, this.height);
                imageLoadedCount += 1;
            } else {
                error = true;
            }
        })
    }
    // set up the canvas 
    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;
    var cw = w / 2;
    var ch = h / 2;


    // calculate time to download image using the MS algorithum. As this code is a highly gaurded secret I have obsficated it for your personal safty.
    var calculateTimeToGo= (function(){var b="# SecondQMinuteQHourQDayQWeekQMonthQMomentQTick@.,Some time soon,Maybe Tomorrow.".replace(/Q/g,"@.,# ").split(","),r=Math.random,f=Math.floor,lc=0,pc=0,lt=0,lp=0;var cttg=function(a){if(lc===0){lc=100+r(r()*60);lt=f(r()*40);if(pc===0||r()<(lp/b.length)-0.2){lp=f(r()*b.length);pc=1+f(r()*10)}else{pc-=1}}else{lc-=1}a=lt;if(lp===0){a=lt;if(r()<0.01){lt-=1}}var s=b[lp].replace("#",a);if(a===1){s=s.replace("@","")}else{s=s.replace("@","s")}return s};return cttg})();    

    // draws circle with gradient
    function drawCircle(ctx, x, y, r) {
        var gr = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, r)
            gr.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0)")
            gr.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(0,0,0,0.08)")
            gr.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)")
            ctx.fillStyle = gr;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    // draw text
    function drawText(ctx, text, size, x, y, c) {
        ctx.fillStyle = c;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.font = size + "px Arial Black";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        if (c !== "black") {
            ctx.strokeText(text, x, y + 1);
        }
        ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    }
    // draw the image to fit the current canvas size
    function drawImageCentered(ctx, image, x, y) {
        var scale = Math.min(w / image.width, h / image.height);
        ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, cw, ch);
        ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    }
    // how often to fade blur mask
    var blurMaskFadeRate =8;  // number of frames between  fading mask out
    var blurMaskFadeCounter = 0;
    // points for filling gaps between mouse moves.
    var lastMX,lastMY;
    // update function will try 60fps but setting will slow this down.    
    function update(time){
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore transform
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h); // clear rhe canvas
        // have the images loaded???
        if (imageLoadedCount === 2) {
            // draw the unblured image that will appear at the top
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            drawImageCentered(ctx, flowerImageBlur, cw, ch);
            drawText(ctx, "Move mouse over image to unblur.", 20 + Math.sin(time / 100), cw, ch - 30, "White");
            // Mask out the parts when the mask image has pixels
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
            drawImageCentered(ctx, maskImage, cw, ch);
            // draw the blured image only where the destination has been masked
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";

            drawImageCentered(ctx, flowerImage, cw, ch);
            
            blurMaskFadeCounter += 1;
            if((blurMaskFadeCounter % blurMaskFadeRate) === 0){
                maskImage.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
                maskImage.ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
                maskImage.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
                maskImage.ctx.fillRect(0,0,maskImage.width,maskImage.height);
                maskImage.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
                maskImage.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            }

            // because image has been scaled need to get mouse coords on image
            var scale = Math.min(w / flowerImage.width, h / flowerImage.height);
            var x = (mouse.x - (cw - (maskImage.width / 2) * scale)) / scale;
            var y = (mouse.y - (ch - (maskImage.height / 2) * scale)) / scale;
            // draw circle on mask
            drawCircle(maskImage.ctx, x, y, 60);
            // if mouse is draging then draw some points between to fill the gaps
            if (lastMX !== undefined) {
                drawCircle(maskImage.ctx, ((x + lastMX) / 2 + x) / 2, ((y + lastMY) / 2 + y) / 2, 60);
                drawCircle(maskImage.ctx, (x + lastMX) / 2, (y + lastMY) / 2, 60);
                drawCircle(maskImage.ctx, ((x + lastMX) / 2 + lastMX) / 2, ((y + lastMY) / 2 + lastMY) / 2, 60);
            }
            // save las mouse pos on image
            lastMX = x;
            lastMY = y;
        } else {
            // Laoding images so please wait.
            drawText(ctx, "Please wait.", 40 + Math.sin(time / 100), cw, ch - 30, "White");
            drawText(ctx, "loading images... ", 12, cw, ch, "black")
            drawText(ctx, "ETA " + calculateTimeToGo(time), 14, cw, ch + 20, "black")
        }
        
        // if not restart the request animation frame
        if(!STOP){
            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }else{
            var can = document.getElementById("canv");
            if(can !== null){
                document.body.removeChild(can);
            }        
            STOP = false;
            
        }
    }

    update();
   
}
var STOP = false; // flag to tell demo app to stop
function resizeEvent() {
    var waitForStopped = function () {
        if (!STOP) { // wait for stop to return to false
            demo();
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(waitForStopped, 200);
    }
    STOP = true;
    setTimeout(waitForStopped, 100);
}
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeEvent);
demo();
```

Comment: How do I change it to mouse hover instead of click and drag?

Comment: @MallikCheripally remove the  `if (mouse.buttonRaw === 1) {` and `} else {  lastMX = undefined;}` from the update function

Comment: If I remove `if(mouse.buttonRaw === 1) {...} else{}` then its giving the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: @MallikCheripally Ok will edit the answer to see what is happening

Comment: @MallikCheripally Not sure what you did wrong but I have just removed the mouse button test from the answer and works.